# Fluid Width On a Block Element Containing A Horizontal List

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. Working on a php script, I must first get the HTML/CSS down right. My goal is to write a vertical menu, that shows a horizontal list sub menu, containing more vertical menu lists.

The problem I'm having is my horizontal list with my block element will not appear horizontal, not unless I add a fixed width to the block element. Is there a way around that?

Sample Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#vertimenu {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
ul.main-links {
    background: none;
}
ul.main-links li {
    background: #999;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
}
ul.main-links li:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
ul.main-links li div.sub-container {
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
ul.main-links li:hover div.sub-container {
    background: #999;
    display: inline-table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
}
ul.sub-categories {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.sub-categories li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}
ul.sub-links {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}
ul.sub-links li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #999;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="vertimenu">
    <ul class="main-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="sub-container">
                <ul class="sub-categories">
                   <li>Category A
                       <ul class="sub-links">
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li>Category B
                       <ul class="sub-links">
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li>Category C
                       <ul class="sub-links">
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you add a fixed width of about 500px to the .sub-container, then the horizontal list within it works. I cannot add a fixed width because it wouldn't work as intended when I add in my php. I tried using other display values besides block, but none do the trick.

I suppose I could use a table instead of a horizontal list within my display:block element, but I would like to avoid that if possible because it's not really tubular data. **EDIT**: using a table has the same issue as the horizontal list, so that won't work properly either.

Sorry if i don't make sense, I'm not an expert with proper terminology...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the lists are being constrained to that width is because is inheriting the width from `#vertimenu` and `ul.main-links li`, which is set to `width: 150px;`.

Remove those set widths and give `ul.main-links li` a width of `150px` instead.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rfeUe/

Comment: ok, I can remove the 150px from #vertimenu. I'm confused about the second part though. You say remove it from ul.main-links li, but then add it to ul.main-links. li instead? What would be the point in removing it just to add it right back? I don't think you meant to say that, right?